# The numbers, Mason, what do they mean?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, language, geography

I'm made up of:

> __ colours of magic
>   __ poules françaises
>   __ gestation months
>   __ nations playing rugby
>   __ friends of Balthazar
>   and also
>   __ is imaginary squared
>   __ six mod three
>   __ days of Hanukkah
>   __ towers of Tolkien

What am I?

**HINT 1**

> Split the two parts up and convert to 3dp

**HINT 2**

> Check the tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Partial:

colors of magic:

> **5** colors in the game Magic: The Gathering (green, red, blue, black, white)

poules francaises:

> **3** French hens

gestation months:

> **9**

nations playing rugby:

> **6**

friends of Balthazar:

> might be **2** other biblical Wise Men or Magi?

is imaginary squared:

> **-1** (the number i squared)

six mod three:

> **0**

days of Hanukkah:

> **8** nights, but that might mean **9** days?

towers of Tolkien:

> **2** as the name of the second novel, although after a bit of googling it may be **3** White Towers

total (wrong):

> again, this probably isn't right but putting this all together, you get **53962-1082**, or **52880**?

total (maybe right?):

> using the GPS coordinates (thanks @rhsquared for finding this idea) 53.962, -1.082 puts me (according to the thing I'm using) in "Top of York Minster", in the UK.

Comment: One of your answers is incorrect, but otherwise, you're doing well, +1

Comment: I realised one of the clues had several answers so changed it. Also your final answer is missing a number (and not doing the correct thing)

Comment: On the ones you're unsure of, the first numbers are correct

Comment: The first one could be 2 - White and Black magic.  Or it could be 8, from the Discworld series.

Comment: The numbers in your final answer are correct, what you do with them is not. Have a look at hint 1

Comment: still not quite right, but very nearly there. The coordiantes have equal precision

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu You could have quoted me that I came first with the coordinates idea.

Answer (score 2):

A blind guess:

> As there is a geography tag, I'm assuming that the answer from @ExcitedRaichu are coordinates which point us at Travemunde, Germany https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/53%C2%B057'43.2%22N+10%C2%B049'12.0%22E/@53.9633143,10.812969,16.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d53.962!4d10.82

Comment: You're on the right line but your decimal point is in the wrong place. (and pay attention to the sign of the number)

Answer (score 1):

> Using the two previous answers from @ExcitedRaichu and @rhsquared, the coordinates seem to be 53.962, -1.084, thus I think that you are pointing to the great statue of Constantine that is near York Minister : https://www.google.com/maps/place/Constantine+The+Great+Statue/@53.9623292,-1.0841092,17z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x487931a5d58341b1:0x97daca52f7800d35!2sCath%C3%A9drale+et+%C3%89glise+M%C3%A9tropolitaine+de+Saint+Pierre+%C3%A0+York!8m2!3d53.9623292!4d-1.0819205!3m4!1s0x487931a673e7f679:0x119de7fe97ee3ed4!8m2!3d53.9618374!4d-1.0817423